# How extract the package source into the some other directory in buildroot

Tags: net-snmp, buildroot

Here my package is net-snmp.
Here is the task : Addition of Net-SNMP Source directory at path personal/apps/snmp/

Requirement is that it should download from website if there is change in version name and it should patch , configure and build soruce.
Hence, for that we need to configure Config.in and netsnmp.mk files in build/package/netsnmp in order to fulfill this requirement.

By adding  following configuration in netsnmp.mk

```
NETSNMP_VERSION = 5.7.2.1
NETSNMP_SOURCE = net-snmp-$(NETSNMP_VERSION).tar.gz
NETSNMP_SITE = http://www.sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/files/net-snmp/$(NETSNMP_VERSION)
```

We can download the latest net-snmp tar ball which will be downloaded in dl/ folder in buildroot.
From here it will untar in build/output/build and will patch configure and build. After that it will build the executable at appropriate location inside target folder.

Here the issue is I want netsnmp source code to be at personal/apps/snmp folder which seems to be problematic and can edit the source in path personal/apps/snmp/ and configure build from here.

Any help and suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a netsmp package in Buildroot. Why do you want to create another one?

Also, the Buildroot community is going to be much more reactive if you ask questions on the project's mailing list.

Comment: I don't want to create ...I want to sync the contents inside my folder and build folder...so that if I change something in my folder, it should be available in build folder when it build or configures.